# How to check if a fullscreen application is running with a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to check if a fullscreen application is running with a batch file.
I know it's possible via command line in Ubuntu and I hope it's possible on Windows aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows doesn't have full screen applications. Windows merely remove titlebars etc and make their client area the same as the monitor to appear full screen. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353

Comment: Yes, it is. Use the  [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) command.

Comment: @Stephan - From `TASKLIST /?` it does not appear that a filter is available related to screen size/setting. In what way could `TASKLIST` be used to accomplish this goal?

Comment: @user3517658 - Are you wanting to know if your currently running app is full screen or if there is any app on the system running in full screen mode?

Comment: It isn't possible in cmd, but Have a look at [GetWindowLongPtr](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLongPtr.html)